# 403 errors on Azure hosted application when attempting to read from files

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-403

I have some code uploaded to an Azure App Service that runs locally fine, but was throwing an error saying that the database connection had been forcibly closed when attempting to return the contents of a CSS file back as a string using WebClient.DownloadString. I tried to get round this by instead reading from the file as below:

```
var url = new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Content("~/commonFiles/formview.css")).AbsoluteUri; 
var cssTemplateBase = string.Empty;
        var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (var response = req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
                {
                    cssTemplateBase = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

But this now throws the 403 Forbidden error when I call GetResponse. I am new to Azure, but feel both errors are probably related and Azure configuration specific.

Edit - Added code generating url variable with path to file

Comment: What is in the URL?

Comment: Have updated code example

Comment: Can't test it now, but I think you should not use `~`.

Comment: The tilda resolves it to the root of the directory and it works both locally and deployed to a non Azure server. Only on Azure does it result in 403 error